# Column 'Products.CDF_Code_Tx' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions

I am not understanding this Error message.

```
Column 'Products.CDF_Code_Tx' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Any guidance on how I could get around this , I think I need a `GROUP BY` clause in but when I place one it makes a lot of things ambiguous.

Here is my code.

```
Select Cdf_Code_Tx, ProjectNo,(CDF_New_des1_Tx+CDF_New_des2_Tx) As Description,Max(Convert(Date, [Last Call Back],103)) As LastCallBack
From Products
     Inner Join SpecDetails On CDF_Code_Tx = ProductRef
     Inner Join Projects2 On ProjectNo = PID
Order By (Convert (Date, [Last Call Back], 103))
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's quite a clear error message, add your `GROUP BY` with every column which isn't being used for an `aggregate` function. E.G. `MAX()` or `SUM()`.

Comment: The main reason of this error is that you are using MAX() in select list and in `ORDER BY` clause. It's not clear what you want to select with this query.

Comment: I am wanting to make my [Last call Back] column the column in which the table sorts itself by with the last entry in [LastCallBack] being Top row in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Aggregate functions in the SELECT clause  list provide information about each group instead of individual rows*... Read more [GROUP BY (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx)

eg.
By doing something like below will lead to error ***"invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause"***

```
Select T1.Col1,T1.Col2,MAX(T2.Col1)
From Table1 T1
    Inner Join Tabel2 T2 ON T2.Id = T1.ID
```

What you shoud do is

```
   Select T1.Col1,T1.Col2,MAX(T2.Col1)
    From Table1 T1
        Inner Join Tabel2 T2 ON T2.Id = T1.ID
   Group By T1.Col1,T1.Col2
```

Comment: I've just tried what you asked & it makes everything ambiguous.

Comment: What you mean by *ambiguous*?